# Asp.Net MVC 3 Free Text Editor with File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce, ckeditor, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I spent all day yesterday looking for a text editor for my Asp.Net MVC 3 application without any joy. What I am looking for is a text editor that I will use to allow a user to add a news story. Therefore, it would be nice if when using the editor the user, as well obviously adding text, could embed an image by hitting an image icon and browsing to their local drive. And also to highlight text, ie 'Further Info', and be able to link to a document which they can also upload.

I know you might think reading this that there are loads of tutorials etc on the Web that already explain that, but after a full day of researching yesterday I have not been able to find any. Either the documentation is for asp.net Web Forms, or PHP etc, but I can find hardly any info on how to implement this for MVC.

I know that the likes of CKEditor and TINYMCE are availble, but I can find no information on how to implement these to my requirements stated above.

If anyone knows of any tutorials or even any alternatives that I could use it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. A solution for tinymce: http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/TinyMCE-Image-Upload-Plugin-for-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this is for Web Forms. I am looking to integrate with MVC.

Comment: oh well, this might be difficult to find